# C# console Application delete files and folders

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete folders and files, once this has been completed and then want to unzip a new compressed folder to the location of the deleted folders and files....

so basically

Delete old folders and files 
extract new folder and files

can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? the delete part is stopping it, if i remove the delete part it works ok...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;


namespace unZipMe
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //provide the folder to be zipped
            //string folderToZip = @"c:\Temp\ZipSample";


            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract");
            DirectoryInfo file = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract");

            //foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete(true);
            }
            //foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                di.Delete(true);
            }


            //provide the path and name for the zip file to create
            string zipFile = @"c:\Temp\ZipSampleOutput\MyZippedDocuments.zip";

            //call the ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory() method
            //ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folderToZip, zipFile, CompressionLevel.Optimal, false);

            //specif the directory to which to extract the zip file
            string extractFolder = @"c:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract\";

            //call the ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory() method
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFile, extractFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

error message

> 'unZipMe.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'unZipMe.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   DefaultDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\name\Dropbox\BegASPNET\unZipMe\unZipMe\bin\Debug\unZipMe.exe'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'unZipMe.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: unZipMe.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'unZipMe.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   unZipMe.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. The program '[16164] unZipMe.exe' has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Are you compiling in release mode? Why not just do `di.Delete(true);`? And then recreate the directory instead of looping through the contents?

Comment: Which part of the code, the Delete? The extraction for the compressed folder?  Also Ron has a valid point, looks like your in release instead of debug.  Also what does Console.WriteLine(file); and other items as your iterating through your code tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Delete() invocation on an instance of DirectorInfo  will succeed only if the directory is empty.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract");
di.Delete(true);
```

The above code will fail if C:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract folder is not empty and will throw IOException (which seems to be the case with your folder since you have mentioned this is the target folder of a zip extraction).

Instead you can use Delete static method on  Directory class with second parameter as true in order to recursively delete any subdirectories and files within that folder.

```
Directory.Delete(@"c:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround if deletion is not necessory:

Since the extract path is in temp directory, you can let the system do the deletion. On the other hand, creating a new extract directory with `GUID` every time you do unzip operation.

```
var extractFolder = Path.Combine(@"c:\Temp\ZipSampleExtract\", Guid.NewGuid());
Directory.CreateDirectory(extractFolder);
```